# Jersey rest MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/jso

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I want to use embedded jet and jersey. 
TEXT_PLAIN work fine but when I use APPLICATION_JSON I got that error:
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class adburst.dao.Campaign, genericType=class dao.Campaign.

Here is the code:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;

public class AdServer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Server server = new Server(8080);
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/",       ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    ServletHolder jerseyServlet = context.addServlet(ServletContainer.class, "/*");
     jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(1);
     jerseyServlet.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");
         jerseyServlet.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.packages","com.addburst.adserver");

    try {
        server.start();
        server.join();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Dependencies:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.restfb</groupId>
            <artifactId>restfb</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0-rc3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.facebookapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>facebook-java-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support: <dependency>   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId> 
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
        <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
        <version>0.99</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

Comment: Have you tried uncommenting the section that tells you to uncomment it for JSON support?

Comment: I think that @chrylis makes a very good point...

Comment: I don't understand what to uncomenting? do you have an example

Answer (score 0):

**I found it!**
I changed the version of org.glassfish.jersey.containers and org.glassfish.jersey to 2.5 and it works!